# Facebook Credit Offerwall - Mobile

Tags: facebook, mobile, credits

Specifically on the Mobile Platform, does support the Facebook Offerwall? [Facebook Offerwall](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/credits/offers/)

We have the feature implemented on our canvas application, but am not able to reproduce on our mobile implementation.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/pay/

> This dialog is only supported in our Dialog page mode via our Graph API, but is also available in our JavaScript SDK. It is not available in iframe, popup mode, or mobile via our SDKs.

So there is no mobile version at present.  You will need to redirect your mobile users to the desktop website version.

Comment: Maybe my question is a little confusing, but this isn't the issue I was trying to address. The Facebook Credit Dialog is operating fine and well on Mobile: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/credits/.

This option also supports a mode, Earning Credits via Offers. I cannot seem to get this portion working in a mobile environment. It throws an exception.